# OData v4 Changeset behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm implementing an OData v4 Service with WebApi and I also implemented support for OData Changesets using the code from https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/web-api-odata-v4-batching-part-10/

Basically this is working, but now I'm wonder about the correct behaviour when modifying the same entity from multiple requests in one changeset.
Consider this example:

Content-ID: 1 - POST ~/Entity
-> Create new Entity.

Content-ID: 2 - PUT ~/Entity($Entity-ContentID1)/Company/$ref?$id=URI
-> Create link from new Entity to existing Company using the ContentID.

Content-ID: 3 - POST ~/Entity($Entity-ContentID1)/ChangeState
-> Execute action to change the state of the newly created Entity.

The ChangetState can only be executed, if a Company is linked. If a client sends all requests in this order and if I execute the requests in order, everything is fine.
But according to the [OData Spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398362), requests in a Changesets are **unordered**.

What is the expected result if a client sends request 3 before request 2? With my current implementation this changeset will fail, but is this really okay?
It's quite hard for me to understand the correct semantic of changesets...

Answer (score 0):

Batch requests are submitted as a single HTTP POST request to the batch endpoint of a service, these requests in a Changeset should be sent to service and proceed in original order.

I think, the spec mean: requests in Changeset will be processed un-order, in our lab, we process with origin order, but different service can use different order, what you concerned is not necessary, client should'n expect same result for a changeset like your scenario, otherwise they should put in different changeset, then the result should be same.

Comment: My own client sends request in the expected order. But the Spec does not require this. Sending request 1 and 2 in reverse order is e.g. no problem (in theory): The dependency of request 2 on 1 is obvious and the service can reorder them. But for request 2 and 3 this is not possible.
I'm just not sure, why the spec does not require ordered requests. I know the answer from [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21939972/2075207), but I'm still unsure.
The SAP guys e.g. seem to support [unordered changesets](http://tinyurl.com/p67s2k9).

Comment: currently you can customize the batch handler to rollback or stop, when error occurs while process those request.

Comment: I already rollback the changeset as soon as an error occurs. My problem: Sequence 1,2,3 is correct, but 1,3,2 leads to an error.
I think according to the Spec this behaviour is not correct, because the order of request should not matter

Comment: I think your service behavior is right, in client side, we can set reqeust 1, 2 content-id = 1, and reqeust 3 content-id=2

Comment: According to the spec, a content-id must be unique and it might contain letters and digits, therefore ordering by content-id is not possible.