# C# OData V4 batch request

Tags: c#, request, odata

We are implementing `OData batch request` in our `OData` endpoint, in order to be able to send multiple operation in single request. So, the one of the reasons of implementing `Batch request` is to be able to create `Invoice` and `InvoiceDetails` in single request. If there is any error or validation message in context, the entire operations should be roll backed(undo all changes).

I have unit test that creates 2 entities in single batch request, first entity with correct value, so it is gets saved to DB, but the second entity has error(or message in context) it will create the message. In response I see first entity is created and the second entity is not. So what should I change to be able to roll back entire request operation and if there is any error it should not save to DB.
I tried with EnableContinueOnErrorHeader and without, but still the first entity gets saved to DB.

```
config.EnableContinueOnErrorHeader();
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just now found the similar question and reading that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373362/transactional-batch-processing-with-odata

Comment: no solution still....